# Adaptative CSS height in MDL

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, height, material-design-lite

I have a website based on MDL, and I have a big header, in the center. I put a box behind, to see the text.

[Here is the CodePen](http://codepen.io/felixinx/pen/xGJJyL).

The goal, is when people resize the window, such as mobile, the box get resized at the text height.

How can we do this?

This is my CSS;

```
.non-logged-in> .title-header-back {
        position: fixed;
        height: 100px;
        padding: 16px;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.title-header {
        color: #fff;
}
```

And my HTML

```
<main class="mdl-layout__content mdl-typography--text-center">
    <div class="non-logged-in">
    <div class="title-header-back">
           <h1 class="non-logged-in title-header">Un bus à votre image</h1>
    </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than setting a fixed height of 100px, set it to `min-height:100px`.

Comment: Oh it's ok. CodePen dosen't displayed it nicely, but it looks better now and functional. Thanks!

Comment: Then why don't you remove height altogether? the div with the opaque background will take the height of its content.